# Difference between pointers in C and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, pointers

Today when i was typing a method in my Objective-C project's, I examined this line:

```
card=self.cards[index];
```

where "card" is a pointer to an instance of My class "Card" ( and Card is a subclass of NSObject ).

In C, if card is a pointer, this syntax is wrong because I have to add the '&' character between '=' and the name of the array.

So, why this difference?

Is "self.cards[index]" a pseudo-instruction of a method that returns a pointer or not?

This is the solution I thought of!

Thank you to all!

The whole method is :

```
-(Card*) drawRandomCard{
Card *card=nil;

if ([self.cards count]) {
    unsigned index= arc4random() % [self.cards count];
    card=self.cards[index];
    [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];

}


return card;
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question; it's a little confusing to follow.  I *think* the answer is that `self.cards[index]` is calling a method on `NSArray`, but it's hard to say since you don't bother telling us what `cards` is.

Comment: Are you sure that `cards` is a pointer? You didn't paste it's declaration/definition, so it's a bit hard to tell. But as @Avi said, if it's a `NSArray` that changes things a bit. Otherwise, this pretty much means `card = this.cards[index];` and there's no pointer(s) there.

Comment: I said "card" is a pointer to Card's class.

Comment: Yes , I've found where I've wrong. 
I confused " card" with " cards " . I'm sorry !

Answer (score 1):

> In C, if card is a pointer, this syntax is wrong because I have to add
>   the '&' character between '=' and the name of the array.

Not true, if the following is true:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} Card;

Card *cards[12];
```

or

```
Card *cards = malloc(sizeof(Card*) * numCards);
```

then this is perfectly valid:

```
Card *card = cards[index];
```

In Objective-C, `self.cards[index]` is also an array of pointers to an object of type `Card`.

So they are not *so* different, in this regard, at least.